# Can we access elements in a HTML via subscript. like p[i], img[i], etc?

Tags: html

Suppose there are multiple `<p>` tags in our HTML page. But we are accessing them through the element name only i.e. `p`. How can we distinguish between them besides the id and the name attribute? Can we access them like via subscript, like `p[i]`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. HTML doesn't let you "access" an element. You need something that interacts with the HTML (such as a programming language) to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to access them with javascript, or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
p[0].innerHTML = 'Hello world';
```